Invariant measures making an action ergodic
Suppose $G$ is a countable (infinite) group acting freely on a standard Borel space $X$. When is there a $G$-invariant measure $\mu$ on $X$ such that that every invariant set has measure $0$ or $1$? The Glimm-Effros dichotomy gives that there is a nonatomic measure making every invariant set have measure $0$ or $1$ if and only if there is the orbit equivalence relation is not smooth, but the measure you construct is typically not invariant in the sense that $\mu(gA)=\mu(A)$ for each $g\in G$, $A\subseteq X$ Borel (or at least not obviously so). Can you always "fix" the measure in some way to recover invariance?
